# jQuery UI autocomplete from remote datasource example

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on getting jQuery UI autocomplete to work from a remote datasource.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

The sample code calls a php script `search.php`

```
$(function() {
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

**First lines from code snippet from search.php**

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
if (!$q) return;
$items = array( //set a bunch of key-value pairs);
```

What exactly does `$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);` mean?  Doesn't `!q` always evaluate as true causing the .php script to return, thus preventing the rest of the script from executing?

**EDIT**

As a reference if you go to http://jqueryui.com/download and download the autocomplete package, the exact example I'm referring to is referenced in

- development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/search.php
- development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/remote.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strtolower call takes the query string variable term and converts it into lower-case; e.g. search.php?term=TEST results in 'test' being saved in $q. If you're retreiving data from a case-sensitive source then you may want to do this to ensure term values of both 'test' and 'TEST' return the same data.

!$q tests whether $q doesn't have a value; be that because it wasn't passed in the URL or it was empty (search.php?term=).

You can test this logic with the following:

```
<?php
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
echo $q ? '$q was set' : '$q was not set'
?>
```

Output:

> ```
> search.php => $q was not set
> search.php?term= => $q was not set
> search.php?term=TEST => $q was set
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The php snippet you posted will trigger a PHP notice, if `$_GET['term']` isn't set - e.g. if `search.php` was called without the parameter.

I would do this instead:

```
if(!empty($_GET["term"]))$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
else return;
$items = array(...
```

This will make the php return instead of throwing an error, if the parameter is not set.

`if(!empty($_GET["term"]))$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);` will check if the array contains any data at the given key (`[term]` / `search.php?term=something`). This will also implicitly check that the key exists in the array.
If the array is not empty on the `term` index it will convert the data from `$_GET["term"]` to lowercase with the built-in `strtolower()` function 
If it is empty on the given key, it will return - thus preventing the script from continuing

---

### Edit

I'll try to explain the sample code as well:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
```

Converts the GET parameter `term` to lowercase

```
if (!$q) return;
```

Makes the script stop if $q is `NOT` `true` or is empty (empty evaluates to false).
If $q contains anything it will continue with the script.